# 床の法線に合わせて板を回転させる方法

Tags: unity3d

Unity2020でスケートボードゲームの開発をしています。
スケートボード用のオブジェクトの板モデルを、斜面などの床の法線に合わせて回転させる必要があるのですが、上手くいきません。
ヒエラルキーの構造は以下です。
移動や回転を親のPlayerで行い、その子としてModelとBoardオブジェクトがあります。
床に合わせて回転させる必要があるのがBoardオブジェクトです。
[image: ヒエラルキーの構造]

トリックや移動などを行う際、Playerを回転させることで全体の回転を行います。
PlayerのRotationの値が全て0の時は上手く行くのですが、少しでも回転しているとBoardの回転がうまくいかなくなります。

以下は実際に使用しているスクリプトです。
インスペクターで_ReferenceTargetにPlayerを、_RotateTargetにBoardを設定しています。

```
public class RotateObjectFromHitObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject _ReferenceTarget;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _RotateTarget;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag != "Field") return;
        var lhs = _ReferenceTarget.transform.forward;
        var rhs = _ReferenceTarget.transform.right;
        var cross = Vector3.Cross(lhs, rhs);
        foreach (var contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            _RotateTarget.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(cross, contact.normal);
        }
    }
}
```

このコードですと、以下の画像のようにPlayerのRotationが全て０の場合うまくいきます。
[image: PlayerのRotationが全て０]

しかし以下画像のようにPlayerのYを90度動かすと、以下画像のように変な挙動になってしまいます。

[image: PlayerのYを90度動かす]

Playerの回転の状態がどのような状態でも、Boardを床の斜面に合わせるように回転させるには、どうすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: 二つの画像を比較すると、ボードは床面に沿ってではなく、Playerの足に固定された状態で向きを変えているように見えます。
Playerとボードの間の自由度（相互の角度などを、どのぐらいの範囲で変えることを許すか）は、どのように考えていますか？
また、Playerは常に垂直に立っていると想定しているのでしょうか？

Comment: ボードの着地状態時は基本的に床面に合わせて回転をしますが、PlayerのRotationを反映させている必要があります。親のPlayerのYが45の場合、子のBoardもYを45に傾けた上で、床面に沿って回転させる必要があります。またPlayerもボードも360度回転することを考慮する必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回転を適用する順番の問題です。この階層構造ですとローカルの回転で制御するのは難しいので、ワールドでの回転として管理したほうが良いと思います。

```cs
/// <summary>
/// 接地面での回転を設定する
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rotateTarget">このオブジェクト回転を設定する</param>
/// <param name="referenceTarget">このオブジェクトのy軸回転を使用する</param>
/// <param name="normal">接地面の法線</param>
private void SetGroundRotate(GameObject rotateTarget, GameObject referenceTarget, Vector3 normal)
{
    // リファレンスのY軸回転のみを取得
    var defaultRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, referenceTarget.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f);
    // 接地の傾き回転を取得
    var groundRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, normal); // 常に真上を基準
    // ワールドでの回転として設定
    rotateTarget.transform.rotation = groundRotation * defaultRotation;
}
```

実際に使用する際は、常にプレイヤーの回転の影響を受けるため、スケートボードの Update() 等で回転を管理することになると思います。

Comment: 載せて頂いたコードで期待通りの動作をしました。ありがとうございます！